# Knockout.js binding with writeable computed property

Tags: knockout.js

html: (generated my knockoutmvc)

```
<select class="span12" data-bind="options : VehicleManufacturers,optionsText : function(item) { return item.Name; },optionsCaption : 'Select Manufacturer...',value : VehicleManufacturer"
id="VehicleManufacturer">
    <option value="">Select Manufacturer...</option>
    <option value="">AUDI</option>
</select>
<span data-bind="with: VehicleManufacturer">
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</span>
```

script:

```
var viewModelJs = {
     "VehicleManufacturers": [{
         "Id": 5,
         "Name": "AUDI"
     }],
     "VehicleManufacturer": null
 };
 var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModelJs);
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

viewModel.VehicleManufacturer = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return viewModel.VehicleManufacturer;
    },
    write: function (manufacturer) {
        // Populate Model list routine
    },
    owner: viewModel
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryDjs/2/

I may not bed doing the binding quite right, what I'm trying to achive is drop-down cascade as per [this article](http://marcofranssen.azurewebsites.net/knockout-that-cascading-dropdown/), which is working with the code above, except the `"with: VehicleManufacturer"` binding, i.e. the name of selected manufacturer isn't shown.

Comment: I don't fully understand what is your problem. Can you maybe put together a JSFiddle which demonstrates your issue? Because it should work... http://jsfiddle.net/eXcjy/1/

Comment: I've modified the question and created jsFiddle, hope it makes sense.

Comment: As far as I can see, there's no good reason to make `VehicleManufacturer` computed. Why do you feel you need to do so? It's fine as a plain observable (and will work too).

Comment: Ah, so the article was using writable observables... those should have been subscriptions on the observables instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* a `computed` is the wrong thing to use here (the article you linked to is down). A `computed` is generally used when you want to calculate a value that depends on *other* observable properties. Your computed's `read` function just returns the computed itself.

I would rework this to use a normal observable and manually subscribe to changes on that observable:

```
var viewModelJs = {
    "VehicleManufacturers": [{
        "Id": 5,
        "Name": "AUDI"
     }],
     "VehicleManufacturer": null
};
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModelJs);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

viewModel.VehicleManufacturer.subscribe(function (manufacturer) {
    alert('dfdf'); 
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ryDjs/7/

Comment: I agree, I didn't think the `computed` `write` function looked right either.

Comment: The tutorial Tsar was using was giving some really bad advice. Using the writable observable in that way was the wrong way to implement the cascading effect. A subscription would have been the most sensible approach.

Comment: i did have a suspicion using computed isn't right here and also confusing. thanks for confirming it.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this what you were trying to accomplish](http://jsfiddle.net/LBbk3/)? The fiddle was broken because you did not have a reference to `ko.mapping`.

#### Update:

Andrew is right, you should not use `computed`s to write values. `Computed`s should be read-only. Use them when you want to derive a value from other values.

I have [another fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3GUuR/) that solves your problem. It uses a `computed`, but you could also do this with a `subscribe`.

Comment: thanks for fixing the fiddle. this is what i have. the problem is, as you can see in your own fiddle, the Manufacturer Name binding doesn't seem to work in the `<span>`. The question is how come?

Comment: How come? Many reasons. Bottom line is it is working now the updated fiddle link I posted.

Comment: Welcome. Definitely use subscriptions to cascade dropdowns. The computed works for getting your manufacturer name, but (hopefully) you should only need the Id for cascading.